# Nut flush draw shove

Tags: drawing

I tried finding an answer on a few sites first, but couldn't.

Just wondering about nut flush draws on the flop.
Hopefully I give enough info here, but I am just wondering if the following is the correct play.

I have A♥ 6♥.

It's an aggressive enough game.
I call a `3bb` raise pre flop. (I realise this is where I went wrong in the first place, but I am more interested in my flop play).
Of those in the pot on the flop, I'm first to act after the blinds.

4 players see the flop.
Pot is 12 BB.
Flop comes Q♥ 7♥ 2♠.

Big blind checks, I check, 3rd to act bets the pot.
4th calls.
Big blind folds.

The pot is now 36BB.
I've about 40BB left, and I shove.

I put the opponents on `QQ+ KQ AQ`

My question though, even if I know I am not the favourite to win the pot, is shoving for 40bb into a pot of 36bb profitable in the long run.

I've a 35% chance of winning the pot (I don't think either opponent will fold to my bet).
So how I look at it, if I contribute less than 35% of the pot, with a bet, it's profitable in the long run, as I will win 35% of the time (Barring the board pairing).

So betting 40bb into a pot of 36bb, and there being two callers means there is a final pot of 156.
My bet was 40bb, and the pot was 36bb, and I was confident both players would call.

So how I saw it was, my 40bb bet, would be for about 25% of the pot at the end of that street, and I would end up winning the hand 30-35% of the time. (30-35 as I think the board might pair and I'll lose about 5% of the time I hit my flush)

I usually see people call an all in in this situation, as obviously the pot odds are better, but I was just wondering.
This kind of shove is something I do quite a bit online, even though I know, I am usually not a favourite going in, but because of the odds, I believe it is the correct play in the long run.

So getting some info on this, would be helpful, and if this is a poor play, it is something I will have to stop doing, as it's something I can easily stop myself doing (I only started doing it because I thought it makes money long term).

Answer (score 3):

On a strict mathematical basis, no, this is not a good play. You are getting 1-1 odds on your money when you need more like 2-1 just to break even.

***However***, you can introduce fold equity into this line of thinking. Fold equity in a nutshell: if you can get opponents to fold, then your hand/odds/draw don't matter nearly as much.

So the part that I would change is the check on the flop. I would absolutely shove on that hand. First, that board is going to miss quite a bit of people's ranges. You could also push something like a weak Q off that hand with a shove. Second, the initial, early shove shows a lot more strength than a check-shove, which can be an akward play in this spot. The goal is to put your opponents into question for all their checks; if you let them put some money in already (like after your check) then they feel "priced in" and your fold equity is a little lower than what it could otherwise be.

Worst case scenario, they call you and you're very much alive in the hand - there's basically nothing that has you dead to rights on that board. Best case scenario, you take down a good pot right on the flop.

Comment: No he is getting over 2:1 with two callers

Answer (score 3):

I think you overplayed your *suited ace*.

**Preflop**

Calling with A♥6♥ pre-flop a typical raise isn't so bad of a move if you plan to play it mostly for the flush potential and against a *loose crowd*, as this going to increase your implied odds *sky high* and this should be the #1 reason to enter cheaply. The great possibility of *multi-way pot* should be your prime reason to play this hand. So it's ok to enter and take that risk.

**Flop**

Ok, you hit your *nuts* flush draw so you're in good shape, especially because the pot is multi-way and there bigger % someone has a hand to fell in love with. Someone **bets the pot** in this situation which is OK nothing to fear / panic about. There was `12 BB`, someone make it `24 BB` and another makes it `36 BB`. It cost you `12 BB` to win a pot of `48 BB` so the pot gives you `25%` equity. Your flush % to the showdown is about `35%` so you have the equity to shove. But the problem is that you **don't have fold equity** here. Loose aggros are going to call you no matter what and `most of the time you're going to get beaten`. Personally the only hands i play that way are when i have combo-draws, like:

having K♥Q♥

on J♥T♥4♠

Your hand is a *coin-flip against 2 opponents*, since you're praying for that little ♥. However with a *combo-draw* you get increased around `70%`. Personally i don't like to get all-in against loose opponents as i want some `fold equity`. Effectively, you just got `all-in` with `50%` equity against aggros.

Personally, i would just call the bet *on the flop* after a pot-raised bet and the call. If there was not a call and knew that player is going to barrel `again` on turn i would fold as well. In short, i like to continue beyond the flop vs `loose-passive` opponents, not with maniacs. Don't try to win every hand. Call the bet and fold any barrel on the turn that goes beyond the odds; call min-raises or keep checking. You have a draw and don't play against tight players, just get in as cheap as possible.